# Splunk Dashboard Studio Drilldown on one Table Column

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have created a Dashboard using the Splunk Dashboard Studio which has a table visualization. Have then added a "customUrl" Drilldown and used one of the table column value as a token on the custom url.

The Drilldown URL is working as expected, but the drilldown link is added to all the columns. I want to restrict the drilldown link to be available on the single column which is being used as the token.

Below is the current code for the table visualization:

```json
{
  "type": "splunk.table",
  "dataSources": {
    "primary": "ds_Yu8QvBzy"
  },
  "options": {
    "count": 25,
    "tableFormat": {
      "align": "> table |pick(alignment)",
      "rowBackgroundColors": "> table | seriesByIndex(0) | pick(tableAltRowBackgroundColorsByTheme)"
    },
    "backgroundColor": "> themes.defaultBackgroundColor"
  },
  "context": {
    "alignment": [
      "left"
    ]
  },
  "showProgressBar": true,
  "showLastUpdated": true,
  "eventHandlers": [
    {
      "type": "drilldown.customUrl",
      "options": {
        "url": "https://myURL/$row.myColumn.value$",
        "newTab": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Long shot by try: $row.<fieldname>.value$ where field name is the name of the field you want the value to be

Comment: I am already doing that at ```"url": "https://myURL/$row.myColumn.value$"```  and the custom url is working as expected as well. What I am not able to achieve is to limit the drilldown link to only one column instead of all the columns in the table.

Comment: Submit this though the ideas portal https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Community/current/community/SplunkIdeas
Splunk might go and add this, Studio Dashboards are still missing quite a lot of features that im sure they will be adding